# How do I do a regex OR in Scite 1.6?

Tags: regex, scintilla, scite

I think that it's using an old regex format as the pipe ( | ) doesn't appear to have an effect.

All I'm trying to is quite simple:

canvas|svg|click|mousemove|div

Comment: Try escaping the pipe: `\|`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I think that this version of Scite just doesn't support OR in Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SciTE's regular expressions are very limited. The documentation is [here](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html). Alternatives separated by `|` are not included in its features.